# Vuex: Does dispatch return a promise so that you can chain them?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am not coding my app yet so I can't test it out but if I wanted to chain dispatches, is that possible to make my dispatches run synchronously?

example:

```
this.$store.dispatch('doSomething', {
    'url': '/admin/do-something',
    'user_id': userId,
})
.then(response => {
    this.$store.dispatch('doSomething2', {
       'url': '/admin/do-something-2',
       'user_id': userId,
    })
})
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Answer

According to the [vuex documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#dispatch):

> **dispatch**
>
> dispatch(type: string, payload?: any, options?: Object): Promise<any>
> dispatch(action: Object, options?: Object): Promise<any>

Meaning, dispatch will always return a `Promise` so, theoretically, yes you can chain the dispatches to ensure a specific order

#### Extra

Going further, if these actions always need to happen in this order, consider making a single action that will dispatch each of these individually for you:

**someVuexModule.js**

```js
...
export const actions = {
  async doSomethingMaster({ dispatch }) {
    await dispatch('doSomething');
    await dispatch('doSomething2');
    await dispatch('doSomething3');
    
  },
  doSomething() {},
  doSomething2() {},
  doSomething3() {},
}

...
```